# How to see product of ideals so fast?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Suppose we're in the ring $\mathscr{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, $\alpha=(1+\sqrt{1141})/2$ and we have $f=x^2-x-285$. Then when $k=16$, $f(k)=-45$ and the book immediately says $(16-\alpha)=q_3^2q_5=(3,\alpha-1)^2(5,\alpha-1)$. Why the fast conclusion? When I compute the product of those ideals, I go through lots of struggle to only get an ideal with say 2 or 3 generators still. Supposedly one can get to a principal ideal pretty fast.

I could clarify more:
$3\mathscr{O}=p_3\cdot q_3=(3,\alpha)\cdot(3,\alpha-1)$ and $5\mathscr{O}=p_5\cdot q_5=(5,\alpha)\cdot(5,\alpha-1)$.

Comment: You reference $\alpha$, $q_3$, and $q_5$ but do not define them.

Comment: @KReiser I'm sorry, it's fixed now. And the q's are the ideals after the follow up equal sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm of the ideal $(16-\alpha)$ is $45=3^2\times 5$. As $16-\alpha$ is not divisible by $3$ then $(16-\alpha)=P_3^2P_5$ where $P_3$ and $P_5$ are ideals of norm $3$
and $5$ respectively. But there are two of each, so which? Now $(16-\alpha)+(3)$
must equal $P_3$, so $P_3=(3,16-\alpha)=(3,1-\alpha)$. Similarly,
$P_3=(5,1-\alpha)$.

Comment: WOW, although your notation is a bit different than mine (later edit, so my fault), this explanation couldn't be shorter and clearer! Thank you!